# YouTube Data API Error calling GET [URL] : (500) Backend Error

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to grab all Subscribers of a Channel from the API.
I do this onBehalfOfContentOwner.

And it works. But after 3700 channels i get and 500 Backend Error as response. If i wait 20-30 minutes it works again for another 1000 subscriber and then i get the 500 error again.

```
Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?*****: (500) Backend Error
```

Whats the reason for the 500 Backend Error bug?
Too many Request? Bug in the API? My Quota is total fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some emails with a Google Tech Guy, it seems like a bug in the API. If you get a 500 Backend Error wait some minutes and try again. If you still get a 500 Error try and wait some hours or some days. If you still get the error is a Bug in the API and you should contact them and tell them about the error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to call all in the same script call? or are you splitting it up?

It might be that you are timing out.

Comment: I am getting 50 channels per request in a while loop until there are no channels anymore. And nope i am not timing out.