# Youtube v3 API: Error 500 (BackendError) when uploading a caption file

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm writing some proof-of-concept code to automatically upload captions to existing videos. Here is my relevant code:

```
var file = $('input[type=file]').get(0).files[0];

var metadata = {
    snippet: {
        videoId: 'xKE5LG5Xd9o',
        language: 'english',
        name: 'test'
    }
};
var uploader = new MediaUploader({
    baseUrl: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/captions',
    file: file,
    token: gapi.auth.getToken().access_token,
    metadata: metadata,
    params: {
        part: 'snippet'
    }
});

uploader.upload();
```

When I run this code, I get the following JSON response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [{
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "backendError",
            "message": "Backend Error"
        }],
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Backend Error"
    }
}
```

I can't find any recent information regarding this error response. There is [this old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017737/youtube-data-api-error-calling-get-url-500-backend-error) that suggests this is an API bug, and that waiting for a period of time before trying again will resolve it. However, that does not seem to be working in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience with the library you need to set your language as a BCP-47 language tag. So that means changing "English" to "en".

```
var metadata = {
    snippet: {
        videoId: 'xKE5LG5Xd9o',
        language: 'en',
        name: 'test'
    }
};
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was that simple of a mistake. It'd be nice if YouTube's error responses were more informative.