# YouTube Data API Errors

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've been working on a project that uses the YouTube Data API to source Videos and their channels.

Over the past 2 days we have been seeing a lot of 500 errors from /youtube/v3/channels endpoint. Is there a platform issue?

```html
{
 "error": { 
 "errors": [ 
  { 
   "domain": "global", 
   "reason": "backendError", 
   "message": "Backend Error" 
  } 
 ], 
 "code": 500, 
 "message": "Backend Error" 
}
}
```

Comment: Looks to be LONG know problem...nice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553439/500-error-with-youtube-api?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017737/youtube-data-api-error-calling-get-url-500-backend-error

Answer (score 0):

When using the YouTube Data API v3 demos available in the [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/) *(and when the "**`backendError`**" appears)*, I tend use the try-it functionality available in the YouTube Data API v3 official documentation instead.

Here are some examples:

- [try-it for video.list API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it)
- [try-it for channels.list API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#try-it)

---

If you still get this same error *(or a similar one)* in both sites *(`Google API Explorer website` and `YouTube Data API v3 official documentation website`)*, you have to check your parameters, wait some minutes and try again.

If the problem persists, contact Google support.

Comment: This code has auto retry with exponential back off. The errors are random but usually sustained for 6 hour blocks. As far as "contact Google support". Apparently StackOverFlow is Google's support for the Youtube API :| https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support

Comment: @joshmckin as far as I know, Stack Overflow is NOT tech-support and the "support" available here in Stack Overflow is more related in how to use YouTube Data API and another related YouTube funcionalities, but SO doesn't have the control over the functionality of the API itself, by this I mean, the control of the backend errors, quota administration and all beyond the public available information both in YouTube documentation and Stack Overflow. I have the impression that YouTube/Google doesn't like to handle these kind of situtations and just throw the ball here.